# BadTokenException on android 6 and higher

Tags: android, android-studio

i have a problem that happens just on android 6 and higher which is   `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException`

the error happens in class extends service :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //load value from sharedpreferences cause service is stopping once removed
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    if(r==0 && g==0 &&b==0  && a==0) //all are 0 probably not loaded so load from mPrefs
    {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        r = mPrefs.getInt("red",0);
        g = mPrefs.getInt("green",0);
        b = mPrefs.getInt("blue",0);
        a = mPrefs.getInt("alpha",0);
        Log.e("service",r+"");
    }
    STATE = ACTIVE;
    mView = new LinearLayout(this);
    mView.setBackgroundColor(getColor());
    int LAYOUT_FLAG;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
    }
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mView, params); // the error is here
    createNotification();
}
```

what is the problem exactly and how can fix it ?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace. with indicating the line number .

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

```
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should grant `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission for Android >= 6.

Like that (call `checkPermission` method from `onCreate` of your activity):

```
private static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

public void checkPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Overlay permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Overlay permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```